# How to change the constrast on ubuntu with terminal or using a KDE tool?

Tags: command-line, kde, screen

I would like change the contrast and not only the brightness. My brightness can be ajusted in KDE using my Fn key, but I would like do it with the contrast too.

Some commands works like

`xbacklight -set 0`

or

`xgamma -rgamma 0.1`, and derivative

but no one change the contrast. Is there a way to adjust the contrast using the terminal or any tool in KDE?

Comment: I think you can only change the contrast using your graphics card settings, what graphics card do you have?

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
as says in lspci

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to run this from the terminal is to use the command:

```
kcmshell4 kgamma
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this myself but the package kgamma /1/ has description:

```
This package contains a settings panel for adjusting the brightness, contrast, 
and gamma-correction of a monitor. Test patterns are shown to help determine 
the settings that accurately display the full range of colors.

Each of the red, green, and blue components can be adjusted individually, 
or all three components can be adjusted together.

This package is part of the KDE graphics module.
```

Links:

1. http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kgamma&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Comment: I had installed the package with `sudo apt-get install kgamma` but there's no entry in terminal to it and the file xf86gammacfg is undocumented too. I think it crashed because looks it isnt to x64 architechture...

Comment: Strange...in repository says amd64 too...but still not working... or I dont know how to call it by terminal

Comment: Looks like kgamma packages only works in ubuntu 11+, i have 10 lts now

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kgamma/+bug/890899

Comment: Tried kubuntu ppa first...not worked. Waiting a replay from kubuntu in launchpad.